# How do I create pairs of keys where only one can be valid but the rest can be nullable in SQL?

Tags: sql

I wanted to create keys using these fields: LOCATION, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4.

The idea was that there LOCATION is mandatory but the other 4 keys are nullable.

There would be 4 possible keys would include (LOCATION, ID1),(LOCATION, ID2),(LOCATION, ID3),(LOCATION, ID4).

If (LOCATION, ID1) has values the other pairs could be null, similarly if (LOCATION, ID2) has values the other pairs would be null and so on..

There only needs to be one non-null pair.

I have tried using primary keys, alternative keys but I cannot seem to achieve my objective.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: From none to four id's per location? I'd consider storing each location/id combination in a separate row.

Comment: Is it SQL server? If so, you can define a computed column on the combination, and persist it, and declare not null, then it can be your primary key. And is location integer or char, and what about id1-4?

Answer (score 0):

One brute way is load constraints over a direct composite key (primary) of all five attributes, like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE usersData (
  LOCATION VARCHAR(51) NOT NULL,
  ID1 VARCHAR(51),
  ID2 VARCHAR(51),
  ID3 VARCHAR(51),
  ID4 VARCHAR(51),
  CONSTRAINT PK_usersData PRIMARY KEY (LOCATION, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4),
  CONSTRAINT CK_usersDataIDs CHECK (
    (ID1 IS NOT NULL AND (ID2 IS NULL AND ID3 IS NULL AND ID4 IS NULL))
    OR (ID2 IS NOT NULL AND (ID1 IS NULL AND ID3 IS NULL AND ID4 IS NULL))
    OR (ID3 IS NOT NULL AND (ID1 IS NULL AND ID2 IS NULL AND ID4 IS NULL))
    OR (ID4 IS NOT NULL AND (ID1 IS NULL AND ID2 IS NULL AND ID3 IS NULL))
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since composite key won't work with nullable keys:

First, create a check constraint -- to check if at least one ID is not null:

```
CREATE TABLE LocationData (
    LOCATION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ID1 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    ID2 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    ID3 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    ID4 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_LocationID CHECK
    (
        ID1 IS NOT NULL OR 
        ID2 IS NOT NULL OR 
        ID3 IS NOT NULL OR 
        ID4 IS NOT NULL
    )
)
```

Then you'll need to make sure the data is unique based on the keys combination:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UC_LocationData_ID1 ON LocationData (LOCATION, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4)
    WHERE ID1 IS NOT NULL;   
GO  

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UC_LocationData_ID2 ON LocationData (LOCATION, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4)
    WHERE ID2 IS NOT NULL;   
GO  

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UC_LocationData_ID3 ON LocationData (LOCATION, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4)
    WHERE ID3 IS NOT NULL;   
GO  

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UC_LocationData_ID4 ON LocationData (LOCATION, ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4)
    WHERE ID4 IS NOT NULL;   
GO
```

Adjust your unique constraints as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, and further assuming these columns are all varchar:

```
Create table yourtable (
Location VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  ID1 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  ID2 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  ID3 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  ID4 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  YourPK as (Location+coalesce(ID1, ID2, Id3, Id4)) persisted not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (YourPK)
)
```